# Много букв (обсуждения своего движка на PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

*Добрый день 
Я как не профессионал в php начал писать свой движок и хотел бы уточнить для себя некоторые нюансы движка.*

**Первый вопрос:**
Стоит ли делать шаблонизатор или можно обойтись заготовками шапки и футер которые вставляются в каждую страницу?

**Второй вопрос:**
Как луче разделять доступность сайта точнее как без ошибочно определять пользователя и грамотно давать ему доступ к страницам только тем которые ему можно (сейчас я сделал так что при авторизации каждому пользователю записывается радномный ключ в базе и потом при какой либо операции берется ключ из сесии и сравнивается который в базе "сам придумал типо од подмены ид")

**Третий вопрос:**
Является ли критичным то что у меня индексный файл загружает страницу=файл в котором и html,php,js

**четвертый вопрос:**
Стоит ли разделять css файлы по страницам?

Comment: вам как непрофессионалу лучше взять готовый движок и шаблонизатор, почитать его гайды и следовать им в части вопросов 3 и 4

Comment: 4. только если стилей слишком много

Comment: 1. Для новичка лучше обойтись заголовками и футером.

Comment: 2. У меня такая же система. Я по этому ключу сравниваю подлинность пользователя и если пользователь подлинный то смотрю есть ли у него доступ проводить данную операцию.

Comment: 3. как для новичка это не критично.

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. PHP сам по себе неплохой шаблонизатор. Можете начать с него.
2. При авторизации пользователю в $_SESSION['id_user'] пишется его id. Можно писать рандомный ключ в базу и пользователю в БД, как вы предлагаете - но так обычно делается, если данные авторизации сохраняются в куках. Так что можно писать в куку рандомный ключ и использовать его для проверки id_user из сессии.
3. Главное чтобы он не загружал файлы, которые не надо загружать. Надо как-то ограничивать список возможных для загрузки файлов.
4. И да и нет. Прикиньте дополнительный трафик и число запросов к браузеру, а также удобство разработки. Найдите оптимум.

Comment: Согласен "PHP сам по себе неплохой шаблонизатор. Можете начать с него." делать нагрузочные вещи по поиску "{text}" в выводе это странно.